# Why aren't my modifications to image_edit and image_save methods working?

Tags: wysiwyg, redactor

I'm trying to modify [redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/)'s `image_edit` and `image_save` methods to add some functionality.

I'm just wrapping te existing `img` element with a `div` and add another one with a text. When I press the save button in the modal and look at the source in redactor, it appears OK, but when I save the changes, redactor cuts off both `div`s and leaves only the original `img` element and `desc` value from the form.  How can I resolve this?

Original code:

```
$(el).attr('alt', $('#redactor_file_alt').val());

var floating = $('#redactor_form_image_align').val();

if (floating == 'left') $(el).css({ 'float': 'left', margin: '0 10px 10px 0' });
else if (floating == 'right') $(el).css({ 'float': 'right', margin: '0 0 10px 10px' });
else $(el).css({ 'float': 'none', margin: '0' });

this.modalClose();
```

My code:

```
$(el).attr('alt', $('#redactor_file_alt').val());

var floating = $('#redactor_form_image_align').val();

if (floating == 'left') {
    var align = 'left-image';
} else if (floating == 'right') {
    var align = 'right-image';
} else {
    var align = 'ci-image';
}

var imgDiv = $('<div class="' + align + '" />');
$(el).wrap(imgDiv);

if($('#image_desc').val()) {
    $(el).after($('<div class="descr" />').html($('#image_desc').val()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify in the settings `{ removeClasses: false }`